# Installing addon in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bower, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to install ember-simple-auth in ember CLI, but something is wrong.  I have created a new ember CLI project, and run the following to install ember-simple-auth.

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-simple-auth
ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth
```

I also ran `bower install` just to make sure I wasn't missing anything else, and have checked that `ember-simple-auth` does exist in `bower_components`.  However, when I try to import it using

```
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';
```

ember server throws an error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/me/Projects/spa_client/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-8L6qfwzZ.tmp/simple-auth.js'
```

What have I missed?

**Edit**

Ember CLI version:

```
$ ember -v
version: 0.0.46
node: 0.10.25
npm: 1.4.27
```

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';`

Comment: The import path is `'simple-auth/authorizers/base'`. Which version of Ember CLI are you running?

Comment: @marcoow the latest I assume. I installed it through npm yesterday.

Comment: `ember -v` prints out the version you're running.

Comment: @marcoow I've added the version to the question

Comment: Ok, 0.0.46 should work. Currently have no idea though what might be causing this.

Comment: I found the error - it was another line I'd forgotten I'd added: `import Session from 'simple-auth'`.  Should have been `...'simple-auth/session'`.

Answer (score 0):

The ember-cli-simple-auth shim whould import the necessary bits automatically, when faced with ENOENT in similar situations I often find that it can be cleared by simply doing `rm -r tmp` to clear the ember-cli tmp directory and force it to re-build - seems like ember-cli doesn't pick-up some of the new pieces without a complete re-build of the directory structure.

If you dispense with the ember-cli shim and go down the bower route you need to `app.import` in your Brocfile? Something like:

```
app.import('bower_components/ember-simple-auth/ember-simple-auth.js');
```

Comment: No, the Ember CLI Addon imports Ember Simple Auth's AMD build automatically - or should at least.